# Как лучше работать с асинхронностью в nodejs

Tags: node.js, асинхронность, promise

Что лучше колбеки или промисы и async await? Недавно прочитал в коментарии на ютуб, что лучшей практикой в nodejs будет использовать колбеки. Как по мне, то промисы проще и код не такой лапшичный, а с async await так вообще все очень хорошо, если нужно цепочкой выполнять. Но все таки это со стороны моего удобства, а как обстоят дела с общими практиками?

Comment: А в чем разница между коллбеком и промисом, кроме синтаксиса? И как вы представляете  async/await без промисов?

Comment: async await с промисами. Просто промисы можно и без async await. Разница как раз в синтаксисе. Хочу знать как лучше. Очень много кода во всяких примерах библиотек работают с колбеками, а не промисами.

Comment: @НазарКалитюк Используйте async/await, они ведь весьма удобные. И, кстати, можете использовать [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) из ноды.